# Persisted entity missing enum value

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, akka

We're using Hibernate 4 and Spring 4 and have set up a simple DAO to manage a Task entity that has an ENUM field.

In our first unit test an Akka Actor is created which then instantiate a new Task object, sets it's enum field, and persists the Task object via the DAO. Once the Actor has done it's part we're back to the unit test thread and we use the DAO to get the Task object, which it finds but the enum field is null. If I check the database the enum column definitely has a value.

In our second unit test we remove the Akka Actor out of the equation. Instantiate a Task, set enum field and persist all in the unit test. This time when we use the DAO to do a lookup  everything is there, enum field included.

So why in the first unit test we are unable to retrieve a persisted Task with the correct enum value? The DAO scope has not been set so the same DAO instance should be used in both the Actor and inside the unit test.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Could be a lot of things : hibernate session cache, second level cache.. can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks Simone, in the end it was our silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was our bad. When Hibernate sets the object with the enum value it calls our implementation of UserType , at that point we configured it incorrectly. Our code did catch the error but it didn't do anything with it, not even a log statement.